# Unicode character in R-package Authors Name

Tags: r, unicode, r-package

Lots of European authors have Unicode characters in their names such as `Å`, `Æ`, `ø` and `Ä`. How can they have their actual name with these Unicode characters rather than some transformed version of the English alphabet (`Å -> A, Æ -> A, Ä -> A`) when creating R-package. In short, how can I use Unicode characters in author/creator/maintainer name when creating an R-Package.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use it?
It seems to me that it is possible: for exemple [that package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lxb/) use ö

Comment: You can just use unicode equaivalents. For example: The string "verf\u00FCgbar" will be outputted as "verfügbar" in man pages.

Comment: @YCR: The package you have referred me has used those character but when I use them and check it for CRAN, it gives me warning of Non-ASCII character in Authors@R

@Gregor: I am using roxygen2 where the `@author` field has these Unicode characters. When I use \u00FC, I get the warning unknown macro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is some note here:
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/check.html

I quote:

> If you use any non-ASCII characters in the DESCRIPTION, you must also specify an encoding. There are only three encodings that work on all platforms: latin1, latin2 and UTF-8. I strongly recommend UTF-8:
>   `Encoding: UTF-8`